# Best way to delete the Values from the table, duplicate to the list

Tags: excel, excel-2016

### Intro

I Have a table with over 50 users and their installed software which are over 180 different names of software. I also have a list with 70 standard software. I was wondering what the best way is to find out which software is installed next to the the standard per user.

### Question

So basically I would like to subtract the standard software from the table with intalled software and have the extra software as result. I am using Excel 2016.

### Example

I have made a simplified example to explain.

- **Installed software**

[image: Installed software]

- **Standard software**

[image: Standard software]

- **Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer in Excel (No VBA) would be to create a new sheet with the same header, and then put a formula in every cell of your table:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Standard!$A:$A;Sheet1!A2)>0;"";Sheet1!A2)
```

In my example, the sheet named "Standard" includes your Standard softwares like in your examples and the Sheet named "Sheet1" is your first Sheet.

If you need a VBA Solution, the following works:

```
Sub Extract_Standard()

Dim RowsToProcess As Long
RowsToProcess = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To LastCol
For a = 1 To RowsToProcess
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Standard").Range("$A:$A"), Cells(a, i).Value) > 0 Then
    Cells(a, i).ClearContents

    End If
Next a
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The function above works perfect! Only did I have to add $ signs to A:A